# It's Dangerous not recognizing payload

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm using Heroku Scheduler to run a script outside of my app. The script is in the same folder as the run.py and procfile.

```
@manager.command
def run_purge():
    candidates = models.Candidate.query.all()
    print "SECRET KEY --------->", os.environ["APP_SECRET_KEY"]
    people_purged = []
    for candidate in candidates:
        if candidate.status != 0 and candidate.approved == True and over_30_days(candidate.last_status_change):
            payload = reactivate_account_link(candidate.email, 'reactivate_account')
            send_email("Your account is innactive", "TalentTracker", [candidate.email], payload)
            candidate.status = 0
            db.session.commit()
            people_purged.append(candidate.email)
        else:
            pass    
    return send_email("Purge Completed", "TalentTracker", email_to_admin, "purge completed --> {0}".format(people_purged))
```

The script generates a payload using Flask's **It's Dangerous** and the payload is received within the views file within the app itself. This works fine locally. However, when I run live it's giving me an "Internal Server Error". Through Print statements, I figured out it's triggering the BadSignature Exception and I'm exactly sure why. My hunch is that it's to do with the secret key being outside of the app but when I print the secret key it's present!

```
@app.route('/candidates/reactivate_account/<payload>/')
def reactivate_account(payload):
    s = get_serializer()
    try: 
        candidate_email = s.loads(payload)[0]
    except BadSignature:
        print "BAD SIGNATURE", payload, s.loads(payload)
        raise   
    candidate = Candidate.query.filter_by(email=candidate_email).first()
    candidate.status += 1
    candidate.last_status_change = datetime.datetime.now()  
    db.session.commit()
    commit_to_analytics(candidate.candidate_id, None, 4)
    return render_template("test.html")
```

This is what `get_serializer` looks like outside of the app.

```
def get_serializer(secret_key=None):
    if secret_key is None:
        secret_key = app.secret_key
    return URLSafeSerializer(secret_key)

# for getting serialized urls
def reactivate_account_link(candidate_email, path):
    s = get_serializer(os.environ["APP_SECRET_KEY"])
    loads = [candidate_email]
    payload = s.dumps(loads)
    return url_for(path, payload=payload, _external=True)
```

I'm creating it separately outside of the app but the function is the same within. I've tried a version of this where I explicitly call the Secret Key but that didn't work either. Instead of creating it separately should I import it?

----- SECOND UPDATE -----

I got this to work by feeding both `get_serialize` functions - the one in the app and the one outside - a completely new `secret_key'.

However, when I ran the `repr` and `==` on the os.environ["APP_SECRET_KEY"] and app.secret_key the values were the same. The payloads matched too.

When I print this secret key in terminal it appears without backslashes e.g. abcdefghi (which I assumed is correct behaviour). In reality the secret key has backslashes e.g. ab/cd/ef/gh/ij. I'm not sure this is related but thought I would include.

Comment: What does `get_serializer()` look like? Are you using the exact same serializer on both ends?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the contents of `os.environ['APP_SECRET_KEY']` and `app.secret_key` are byte-for-byte the same value?

Comment: Yep, i'm pulling both from os.environ and I checked using print statements.

Comment: No, that is not enough. Use `repr()` on them, and `==` to assert they are indeed equal. Next, validate that `payload` in `reactivate_account_link` is exact the same value as `payload` in `reactivate_account`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, see the second update. I've gotten it to work but it's still somewhat of a mystery.

Comment: Backslashes are escape sequences in many string literal syntaxes. If you have one with and one without them, then the values are **not** equal. It's not clear to me what values you have as you used *forward* slashes (not ``\`` but `/`) in your sample string in your question.